# Блочная подсветка синтаксиса js в редакторе webshtorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Когда указатель мыши находится внутри блока кода, то подсветка синтаксиса происходит только в нем, остальной код за пределами блока не подсвечивается.
Как сделать, что бы код подсвечивался во всем файле независимо от курсора мыши?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]